Does "feasible" mean possible to do or possible to do easily or conveniently?
I have, until now, always thought that "feasible" means that something can be done easily / conveniently / relatively efficiently but I recently read a translated text on inventions that stated that in order to be considered an invention, something had to be "new, inventive and technically feasible". Here the word was used to mean "possible according to the currently valid laws of physics". Is this usage of the word correct? I looked the word up and found definitions stating that feasible = possible but also that feasible = possible to be done easily or with a high chance of success.

In my experience, in the scientific/engineering world the primary meaning of "feasible" just means "possible [within the given timeframe]". You'd use a different word like "trivial" to mean "can be done easily". This may differ from the more colloquial usage. Etymologically, "feasible" comes from the Latin verb facere, meaning "to do/to make" so certainly its root meaning is just "able to be done".

feasible is a formal word for doable.

My experience is similar to Canadian Yankee's: feasible refers to what is possible to do within a set of  constraints (time, budget, access to the necessary talent or raw materials, impact on other things, and so on).  Something can be possible to do and yet not feasible.  doable can have the same meaning ("It's possible, just not doable")  or the unqualified meaning:  "That's not even doable".

Some dictionaries give a definition of 'easily able to be carried out'; others just give, in effect, 'able to be carried out' with no implication of ease or practicality. If you want to be clear in your writing, you could use adverbs - e.g. that something was barely, comfortably, very (etc) feasible:
preventing dangerous climate change by the end of the century is barely feasible
the plan was very feasible
the design of SSTO configurations might be comfortably feasible, marginally feasible, or unfeasible, depending on the parameter values assumed

Outside of writing, in spoken English tone of voice will tell you a lot. If I'm asking a software developer whether she can implement a feature and she says, very hesitantly, "Well...I guess it's feasible..." then that hints that it might be possible but not easy.
